# Entitlement lookup popup window not showing recently viewed anymore

Tags: lookup, entitlements, recentlyviewed

Previously, when looking up an Entitlement from a Case, the recently viewed Entitlements would show up.

Now, even users who have view all accounts and entitlements are not having this functionality. Instead, the popup window says "The search returned more than the maximum number of rows (200). Please refine your search criteria." and shows what are seemingly random entitlements - entitlements that may have never been viewed by the user.

We recently rolled out an update that restricted account accessibility for some users, whereas previously there was a sharing rule that basically shared all accounts with everyone. I can't imagine why it would be relevant, but it was the only change made in the time period that this started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with support, I found out the following, which is wasn't aware of before.

> Please be informed that the behaviour you are seeing occurs because the list of recently accessed records is ordered by their first-accessed date and not last-accessed date.
>
> There are variations in how Lookup Dialog Search operates for
>   different objects however, if a user's list of recently accessed
>   records for a given object exceeds the results limit (e.g. 250, 200
>   for filtered lookups, or 100 for Campaign), an expected recently
>   accessed record may not be returned in the blank lookup's results.
>
> Workaround: Add one or more search terms to the search to make the
>   lookup search more restrictive, so that it returns fewer results than
>   the lookup limit for that object.

My specific problem seems to have derived from the fact that we were using a custom account field and it was not using the Account filter feature. The workaround was to add a lookup filter for the account.